# Verify a distribution that is exponential family

Tags: statistics, self-learning

> Given the parametric class formed by the density functions defined as follows:
>   $$p(y;\theta)=\theta(\theta+1)y(1-y)^{\theta-1},\ y\in(0,1),\ \theta >0$$
>   Does this parametric class forms an exponential family like $$f(y, \theta)=q(y) exp\{\phi(\theta)t(y)-\tau(\theta)\}$$
>   ?

I could write the density function in this way:$$p(y;\theta)=y\exp\{(\theta-1)ln(1-y)+ln(\theta(\theta+1))\}$$

so, if

$$q(y)=y,\ \phi(\theta)=(\theta-1),\ t(y)=,\ \tau(\theta)=-ln(\theta(\theta+1))$$

then the answer should be yes. Is that correct?

Is also correct the relationship $p(y;\theta)=Beta(2,\theta)$?

Comment: It seems OK (and indeed $Beta$).